# How can I download a PDF file from Google Drive?

Tags: download

I've got this PDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gthSy-Vhepdm5YYlc0dk9XUHc/view I'd like to download it to my computer. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The permissions stop viewers from down-loading. You will need to get a different link with down-load permission from the up-loader.

Answer (score 0):

If the owner has disabled printing and downloading for a file, you cannot *directly* download it. The following is an untested and very fiddly method which may work:

- Click 'Add to My Drive' at the top-right
- Open your [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/shared-with-me)
- Right-click the file, select 'Move to' and move it to your computer (requires the Drive desktop app)
- Copy the file out of the Drive folder on your computer

For this particular file, each page is just an image. By opening the viewer (the link you posted) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, opening the `Network` tab and downloading each of the `PNG` images (you may need to reload the PDF tab for the images to appear).

Comment: Sorry, I suggested a solution before testing it. Google's DRM is relatively strong, but the edits above show how to bypass it.